# Win11 Fingerprint scanner stopped working

Tags: windows, fingerprint

My Aorus laptop recently got a failed fan replaced, but since then the fingerprint scanner stopped working. It's showing not compatible with Windows Hello Fingerprint. It's also not showing up in Device Manager. I'm at loss on what to do

Comment: Take it back to the shop that bodged the fan job.

Comment: Yes.  it is a hardware part. May have been disconnected